# "const access error" on sun os when compiling c++ code

Tags: c++, unix, compiler-errors, solaris

Here is my code :

```
class X
{
public:
  X():_x(5){}

  void GetVal(int & oVal)
  {
    oVal = _x;
  }

 private:
  int _x;
```

};

```
class Y
{
public:
  X * const GetX()
  {
    return &_x;
  }
private:
  X _x;
};

int main()
{
  Y y;
  X * p = y.GetX();
  int * pInt = new int[2];
 p->GetVal(pInt[0]);
}
```

In the last line of main, I get an error

> Incorrect access of a member from const-qualified function

This error is observed only when the code is compiled on a sun solaris system and doesn't happen on windows or aix system. Any idea why?

Also the strangest thing is that the error is gone if I replace pInt[0], with a simple integer (int a = 0; p->GetVal(a))

Comment: GetVal is non const is it all code?

Comment: @Denis Yes, GetVal() is indeed non const

Comment: The code looks legal and GCC has no issues with it (except a warning about the type qualifiers in the return type of ``GetX()``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `const` in `X * const GetX()` will be ignored, because the result of the function call is an rvalue and rvalues of non class type cannot be `const` according to [c++ const member function that returns a const pointer.. But what type of const is the returned pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888470/c-const-member-function-that-returns-a-const-pointer-but-what-type-of-const).

Are you sure you didn't mean to write:

```
const X * GetX() const
{
  return &_x;
}
```

that is, you change it from returning a constant pointer to variable date into a variable pointer to constant data, and you declare `GetX()` to be a constant member function, that is a member function that can be used on constant instances of Y: `const Y y;`

Furthermore in `class X`, you can change `GetVal()` to

```
void GetVal(int & oVal) const
{
  oVal = _x;
}
```

Comment: If the question is genuinely honest, its a compiler-specific error (or bug).

Comment: @Micha : The code I have listed is correct(is the code that I intended to paste :-) ). Yes these two points are true and can be done. But my query is as to why this error arises in the code that I have posted. Why constness comes into picture at all when the code is not modifying any class members of X

Comment: @Mark : Oh... I had hoped that this behavior was because of some c++ concept/feature/behavior that I din't know about and the answer to which could have provided me some enlightenment!

Comment: @Arun Are you sure that the error really emanated from the last line of `main()`?

Comment: @Mark Yes. And the strange thing is that the error is gone if I replace pInt[0], with a simple integer (int a = 0; p->GetVal(a))

Comment: @Arun Alright. Since your error message mentioned a `const qualified` I was hoping that changing `GetX` would make it disappear.