# How do I create a struct for storing and returning an array of floats?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I want to create a struct that holds texture coordinates for a square texture. The struct should have only one static member which is a constant array of 8 floats, and only one function, which returns the array.

I tried this:

```
struct TextureCoordinates
{
    static constexpr GLfloat m_texturecoords[8] = {
            1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f,
    };

    GLfloat* const gettexcoords() { return &m_texturecoords; }
};
```

but I get an error saying that the return type doesn't match function type. How do I change this struct to make it work in a memory efficient way?

Comment: Why do you have a `struct` with only a `static` member?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ const member function that returns a const pointer.. But what type of const is the returned pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888470/c-const-member-function-that-returns-a-const-pointer-but-what-type-of-const)

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit, I want the data to be accessible from anywhere, stored only once, and constant. This was the only way I could think of to do that. Do you know of a better way I should implement instead?

Comment: @ViktorAxén Just declare it at namespace scope, i.e. a global? What's the benefit in the class?

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit there is none I know of, declaring it in namespace does seem better, don't know why I thought it had to belong to a class or struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GLfloat* const` means the GLfloat pointer is const, i.e., the pointer not the value it points is const. From https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-ptr-vs-ptr-const:

> Read the pointer declarations right-to-left.
>
> const X* p means “p points to an X that is const”: the X object can’t
>   be changed via p.
>
> X* const p means “p is a const pointer to an X that
>   is non-const”: you can’t change the pointer p itself, but you can
>   change the X object via p.
>
> const X* const p means “p is a const
>   pointer to an X that is const”: you can’t change the pointer p itself,
>   nor can you change the X object via p.

You need to return `const GLfloat*`. Since the method does not belong to a particular object, it can be static.

```
static const GLfloat* gettexcoords() { return m_texturecoords; }
```

**Demo**: http://ideone.com/6f1enU.

Comment: Thanks Yang! I also had to change the return to `&m_texturecoords[0]`, will this cause any problems?

Comment: I edited the answer. You can just return `m_texturecoords`. The array name is automatically a pointer.

Comment: Also note that this solution additionally makes the method const, which means it can be called on const-qualified `TextureCoordinates` instances

Comment: Method can even be `static`.