# Understanding char* - C++

Tags: c++, constants

I am writing a code in C++ right now, and I have a dilemma.

EDIT: I added the class relevant definition

- ****_fullName is defined in the class as a private dm(char* _fullName)***

my class contains the getter method below:

```
char* getFullName() const { return this->_fullName; }
```

However, I had in the past cases in which I returned char* with const(const char*) 
I can change the getter method to this one:

```
const char* getFullName() const { return this->_fullName; }
```

Both versions are compiling but I don't know how to choose.
I would take the second version, but I wonder
 **Why even the version without the const is compiling? shouldn't it give an error when I remove the const keyword, because the function is a CONST member function and therefore the dms are const as well and cannot be returned without the const keyword???**

This is the class relevant definition:

```
class Professional
{
private:
    char* _ID;
    char* _fullName;
    int _age;
    char* _profession;
}
```

Comment: Can’t you simply return a std::string?

Comment: By the way, there’s no issue returning a non const value from a const method.

Comment: of course I can but I want to deeply understand the char* issue

Comment: The pointer is what you are returning. And you are returning it by value.

Comment: @Macmade, if there is no issue then why is this an error?

class A{ 
   int num;
   int* func(const int* anyInt) const{return &num;}

Comment: @drescherjm but i want to return the address so therefore char* type...

Comment: When you put `const` after the method name, that means that the method will not change the state of the instantiated class.

Comment: I think where the confusion is that using the returned pointer you could change the contents of  c-string that the pointer points to.

Comment: @CodeLearner `int` is not `char`.  There are some legacy exceptions in compilers that allow passing around `const char *` as `char *` that don't apply to `const int *`.

Comment: @CodeLearner I am not sure this makes sense. Can you show the declaration of `_fullName` - is it a `char` or a `char *`? - you can't return _fullName if its just a char with a return type of char * or const char * - you would have to return type char or return `&this->_fullName`

Comment: Infact just drop the `this->` part alltogether...

Comment: When writing **getter** member functions like `getFullName() `, the return of a pointer to a private member is not intended to be modified, so `const char *` would be the preferred type.

Comment: This is what I expect to see: https://godbolt.org/z/v1s9o8 No `const` works, all `const` works, mixing `const` fails to compile. Your compiler may have extensions to allow older code from the days when `char` was given some special treatment.

Comment: Why `_ID`, `_age` instead of `ID` and `age`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c++ const member function that returns a const pointer.. But what type of const is the returned pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888470/c-const-member-function-that-returns-a-const-pointer-but-what-type-of-const)

Comment: @user4581301 I concur with this - but this does not match what the OP is saying is happening, so I can't really see how they are getting this to compile which is odd considering the return types are `char *`/`const char *` and the item being returned is apparently a `char` (but I suspect it is not - we can't see what it is yet)

Comment: Basically return or pass `const` whenever you can.  If there's no reason for something to be mutable, then make it `const`.  The way to properly test this would be to actually use it - `char* x = z.getFullName()` vs `char const* y = z.getFullName()`

Comment: @code_fodder Different compilers have different quirks and different rule exceptions and extensions. Asker's probably using an older Visual Studio or an up-to-date one with language compliance turned off.

Comment: i am using VS2019

Comment: @Vargo, I have already read it before posting my post, it was helpful but not in 100%

Answer (score 4):

First understand what `const` attached to a member function *means*. It determines the const-ness of the implicit `this` used for the member. Given this:

```
struct S
{
    char value[10];

    const char *mfn() const { return value; }
};
```

within the confines of `mfn` the implicit `this` is `const S *`. Furthermore, all references to members obtained therein are also `const`. In this case, that means `value` as an expression representation is `const char (&)[10]` before any further conversion are attached therein.

**That's important**.

In the correct posted example above there is an automatic conversion to temporary pointer, since `const char(&)[10]` converts to `const char*` without objection. However, the following will fail:

```
struct S
{
    char value[10];

    char *mfn() const { return value; }
};
```

The reason this will fail is simply because there is no conversion possible. `value`, remember, is `const char (&)[10]`, and can only implicitly convert to `const char*`.

But how could it succeed? Well, consider this:

```
struct S
{
    char *ptr;

    char *mfn() const { return ptr; }
};
```

This will work. The reason is subtle, but obvious once you think about it. `ptr` is a `char*`. The attachment of `const` to `this` makes that `char * const&`, *not* `const char *&` (there is a difference; the former is a reference to a non-mutable pointer to mutable data, the latter is a reference to a mutable pointer to non-mutable data). Since `return ptr` is not mutating `ptr` (or anything else in the object), it is viable as a result.

In short, in your case it works because the pointer you are returning isn't via some implicit conversion from a const underlayment; it's just a value.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few things going on here, in your example of the `int num` member this is *not* the same as a `char *` member.

lets expand your example a bit:

```
class Professional
{

    int* func() const
    {
        return &myInt; // Fails because it returns a reference to a member variable
    } 

    char* func() const
    {
        return &myChar; // Fails because it returns a reference to a member variable
    } 

    int* func() const
    {
        return pInt; // ok because it returns a COPY of the member pointer
    } 

    char* func() const
    {
        return pChar; // ok because it returns a COPY of the member pointer
    } 

    int myInt;
    char myChar;
    int *pInt;
    char *pChar;
```

**Note:** the two pointers getting returned by *copy* are ok. Its the pointers that are copies **not** the thing being pointed to. The memory that is pointed to is nothing to do with *this* class.

As to an answer to your question: there is a rule of thumb that is to apply const as much as possible - this helps to show other users your intent *and* gains benefits from compiler warnings / errors if a user tries to use your class in a way you did not intend. So in this case pass back a `const char *`.

**Note:** See this answer for more specific details here: [What is the difference between const int*, const int * const, and int const *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const)